# How to cast a string to int with multiple positive and negative signs?

Tags: php, integer, signed

I'm trying to cast string to int. Everything work fine but have a small problem here

```
echo (int)"--12"; //return 0, i want 12
echo (int)"---23";//return 0, i want -23
echo (int)"+-99"; //return 0, i want -99
...
```

Why did this happened and what is the right way to cast in this case?
Many thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to just get a returned value of 1 from those strings? or do you want the signed value being they're all -1?

Comment: What is `+-1` supposed to be?

Comment: Brendon Moss: No, not just value of 1, it can be any number.
Andreas: I get it from another string

Comment: I don't care where you get it from, what do you want?

Comment: what are you expected output for each test case? parsing string to int that are not digit will always result to 0 `echo (int)"asd"; //will return 0;`

Comment: Nguyen, what I mean is what are you expecting to parse through under these scenarios? "+-4" and "---9823"

Comment: I have update my question, sorry for my bad english

Comment: why are you expecting --12 to be 12 but ---23 to be -23, is this just a typo in your comment and you mean --12 to be -12? ( sorry or you want it to handle multiple negatives for turning the signed value around? )

Comment: Brendon Moss: Oh, I think you're right. My bad again. It's multiple negative and positive signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate the positive and negative signs so that all positive symbols are ignored and two negatives equal a positive, you can perform a replacement.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2WPCc))

```
$signed_number_strings = ["--1", "---33", "+-444"];

foreach ($signed_number_strings as $string) {
    var_dump((int)preg_replace('~\++|-\+*-\+*~', '', $string));
}
```

Output:

```
int(1)
int(-33)
int(-444)
```

The logic behind the pattern is to first match/remove 1 or more consecutive `+` signs, OR a `-` sign followed by zero or more `+` followed by a `-` (and absorbing any trailing `+` signs).  If there are any fringe cases that my pattern doesn't correctly handle, please update your question and leave me a comment.

p.s. The extension of my 2nd branch with `\+*` is an attempt to optimize the pattern so that it doesn't have to restart the pattern.  It could have been written as `~\++|-\+*-~` which would be slightly less strain on the eyeballs.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BeXAu))

Comment: I did upvote you though as its a solid solution and way less complicated than the one I offered. That being said though and only because its still unclear but any alpha char and the result will be 0.

Comment: The fringe case of alpha characters after the sequence of signs is an "invented 
 fringe case".  There is absolutely no indication of the presences of letters in the posted sample input.

Comment: You're correct, though also no indication of trailing + signs and yet you handled them... why?

Comment: It seems a reasonable possibility for the presented case.  I could remove it if it makes you happy, but there doesn't seem to be much rhyme or reason to the string of signs.  Nah, I'll remove it for you anyhow.

Comment: No need to remove, I still consider your solution solid and think the extra handling is good consideration towards ( lets admit ) an unclear request with difficult to understand use cases which is why I was trying to handle the possibility that the string may contain characters other than numerical values and mathematical symbols and focused only on the first occurrence of a solid number sequence and its possible signed symbol. You're handling the issue much more elegantly and I tip my hat to you and this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure on your use case but I knocked up this function to try and handle a string with numbers and to return the first full number with negative signed support.

I am sure I have your use case wrong but you can butcher this function however you like to drop the negative signed handling or to possibly handle floats where a decimal place may be needed for detection.

Worth noting that a regex may even exist for this.. who knows.

```
function intvaljunk($string) {
    $boolSignedNegative = false;
    $intIntStart = null;
    $intIntEnd = null;
    foreach (str_split($string) as $index => $char) {
        if (is_numeric($char)) {
            $boolSignedNegative = (
                $boolSignedNegative === false
                && $index > 0
                && is_null($intIntStart)
                && $string[$index - 1] === '-'
                    ? true
                    : $boolSignedNegative
            );
            $intIntStart = is_null($intIntStart) ? $index : $intIntStart;
            $intIntEnd = is_null($intIntStart) ? $intIntEnd : $index;
        } else if (!is_null($intIntStart) && !is_null($intIntStart)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (
        !is_null($intIntStart) && !is_null($intIntStart)
        ? intval(($boolSignedNegative ? '-' : '') . substr($string, $intIntStart, ($intIntEnd - $intIntStart) + 1))
        : null
    );
}

echo intvaljunk("--1") . PHP_EOL;
echo intvaljunk("---1") . PHP_EOL;
echo intvaljunk("+-1") . PHP_EOL;
echo intvaljunk("+-14991abc667") . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Could you even explain what this strange algorithm does? Why not use the much simpler approach of eliminating irrelevant signing information?

Comment: Proof that this snippet does not deliver the expected output:  https://3v4l.org/bXp1U

Comment: Nico Haase, I was only intending on providing an initial example for how to parse a string that contains numbers and what I though could have been any number of other characters unknown to be valid numbers. When posted, the OP's description was a vague and kinda still has no clear request other than how to parse a string with numbers and some example expected output that is not explained and only inferred. I did not want to just provide the answer, instead provide thought about how to build a function that could do exactly this or be modified to do extra or less.

Answer (score -2):

you can extract number from string . can help?!

```php
$str = '--1';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: ...and `preg_match_all()` is not a great choice anyway.

Comment: Could you explain your approach? Have you tried it on some more input data to see if it works?

Comment: This ignores the symbols in the same way that `ltrim($str, '+-')` would, but that is not the logic that the OP requires.  This answer is incorrect.